# maximo anywhere barcode scanner and map plugin is not working at iphone

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

ANYWHERE - App Features

1) Enabled "true" in app-features.properties
2) Installed app in device but could't access scanner and Map

Error:
Barcode Scanning - issue in iPad with Error "CodeScanner" plugin missing. 
Map - MapPlugin Missing issue

Error Logs:
2016-01-09 15:26:53.254 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.CodeScanner] scanning code...

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] Sending request using

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] codeScannerType: barcode

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] action: scan

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] parameters: []

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] deferred found!

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.CodeScanner] entering sendRequest...

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.CodeScanner] deferred is: [object Deferred]

2016-01-09 15:26:53.255 WorkExecution[1099:401314] [platform.codeScanner.codeScanner] Calling codeScanner with deferred object

2016-01-09 15:26:53.256 WorkExecution[1099:401314] CDVPlugin class ISICodeScannerPlugin (pluginName: CodeScanner) does not exist.

2016-01-09 15:26:53.256 WorkExecution[1099:401314] ERROR: Plugin 'CodeScanner' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

2016-01-09 15:26:53.256 WorkExecution[1099:401314] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [

"CodeScanner638113505",

"CodeScanner",

"scan",

[

]

]

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because you haven't rerun the "./build.sh update-platform" after enabling maps and barcode.

Can you rerun "./build.sh update-platform all", and see if your rebuilt application works.

We know this is a bit confusing and though we've documented this in version 7.5.2.1 somewhere in a technote, we've fixed so this extra step is no longer required in 7.6

Comment: my machine is windows if i need to install any shall script software or shall i try run build.cmd command?

Comment: Hi i try run the platform update following command are i used to execute. build.cmd clean and build.cmd update-platform

Comment: MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-platform-installer.xml:107: impossible to resolve dependencies:
 resolve failed - see output for details